# I want to create the following menu style by css

Tags: html, css, styles, navbar, bootstrap-4

You can see,

> | Nav --- Logo --- Info |

This is the style I want on mobile.

Nav is left align.

Logo is center align.

Info is right align.

```
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="item">Nav</div>
  <div class="item">Logo</div>
  <div class="item">Info</div>
</div>
```

**What styles do I have to implement for each item to get what I want?**

Please, Thanks.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at it? Research is a pre-requisite of asking on [so].

Comment: sorry, but i can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) make the parent flex and space around the content.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44fv0cmL/)

```css
.navbar{
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/88x88" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <p> Info about the website </p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: May I ask why you think hard-coding `width` and `height` on a menu is a good idea? It's really not. Your menu will look really bad on mobile devices with screen width below `600px`.

Comment: I did not say that. I just did for representation.

Comment: You answered on [so]. Implicitly, you are setting an example for all future visitors with the same problem. Your answer says *"this is the correct method, how it should be done"*. Consider providing answers using best practices and try not to make assumptions. This way your answers will help more people.

Comment: Noted. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

By far the easiest way to achieve this is using `flexbox`. To limit it to mobile devices, you'd need to wrap it in a `@media` query, which, for Bootstrap, is below `768px`

```css
#navbar {
  /* 
   * place non-mobile styles here
   * For example, to hide the navbar outside mobile...
   */
   display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #navbar {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center; /* optional, to center vertically */
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="item">Nav</div>
  <div class="item">Logo</div>
  <div class="item">Info</div>
</div>
```